# Python Read In Google Spreadsheet Using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have file in Google sheets I want to read it into a Pandas Dataframe. But gives me an error i don't know what's it.
this is the code :

```
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = "1HUbEhsYnLxJP1IisFcSKtHTYlFj_hHe5v21qL9CVyak"
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export? 
gid=556844753&format=csv")
print(df)
```

And this is the error :

```
File "c:\Users\blaghzao\Documents\Stage PFA(Laghzaoui Brahim)\google_sheet.py", line 3, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?gid=556844753&format=csv")
  File "C:\Users\blaghzao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\blaghzao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\blaghzao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 581, in _read
    return parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\blaghzao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1255, in read
    index, columns, col_dict = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\blaghzao\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py", line 225, in read
    chunks = self._reader.read_low_memory(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 805, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 861, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1960, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 89 fields in line 3, saw 243
```

Comment: Sounds a lot like a data alignment issue. Pandas is for data with a consistent number of columns while spreadsheet programs can be filled arbitrarily. Looks like you have 89 columns on your first line but 243 on the third.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, the problem it's just with access permissions of the file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5h0OH.png)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Remove gid from code**

```
import pandas as pd
sheet_id = "1HUbEhsYnLxJP1IisFcSKtHTYlFj_hHe5v21qL9CVyak"
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=csv")
print(df)
```

[Click on link for sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGOcG.png)

Comment: No doesn't work. and gid i want it to specify witch spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this error rises using comma delimiter and you have more commas then expected.

Can you try with below read_csv() method to avoid them;

```
df = pd.read_csv(f"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export? gid=556844753&format=csv", on_bad_lines='skip')
```

This will avoid bad lines so you can identify problem depending on skipped lines. I believe your csv format export is not matching with what pandas read_csv() expects.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish the particular sheet to the web and read the web link as csv. Make sure the sheet is accessible to anyone who has the link.

[image]

[image]

Then read the web link to pandas csv

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('published_link')
```